# Locustio (Python) login

Tags: python, http, python-requests, load, locust

I want to make some load tests on the website. 
First of all, that's my code:

```
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task

class UserBehavior(TaskSet):
def on_start(self):
    """ on_start is called when a Locust start before any task is scheduled """
    self.login()

def login(self):
    post_data = {'username':'my_login', 'password':'my_pass', 'Login':'Login'}
    with self.client.post('/sign_in', post_data, catch_response=True) as response:
        if 'cookie' not in response.cookies:
            response.failure('login failed')
@task(2)
def index(self):
    self.client.get("/admin")

@task(1)
def profile(self):
    self.client.get("/profile")

class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
    task_set = UserBehavior
    min_wait = 5000
    max_wait = 9000
```

I  am running locust with: *locust --host=https://my_host*.

Always I am receiving 405 err Error report:

*11                 POST /sign_in: "CatchResponseError('login failed',)"*

Can someone please explain to me how to make sure I am logged in and how to do this with locust?
I am a little confused because I've also tried to make things work with tokens etc., and still the same.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some "silly" things you may need to try, depending on how your API is working, are the following:

1. Try append a trailing slash(/) to your endpoint e.g. `'/sign_in/'` instead of `'/sign_in'`.
2. For some reason, I get an error when I use `http` in my host variable, but it works fine when I use `https`. You might want to try this out too.
3. Make sure you did not forget version in your endpoint if you have one. For example, `'https://my_host/v1/sign_in/'`.

As for logging in with a token, below code works fine for me:

```
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task
import json


class UserBehavior(TaskSet):

    def __init__(self, parent):
       super(UserBehavior, self).__init__(parent)

       self.token = ""
       self.headers = {}

   def on_start(self):
      self.token = self.login()

      self.headers = {'Authorization': 'Token ' + self.token}

  def login(self):
      response = self.client.post("/sign_in/", data={'username':'my_login', 'password':'my_pass', 'Login':'Login'})

    return json.loads(response._content)['key']

 @task(2)
 def index(self):
     self.client.get("/admin/", headers=self.headers)

 @task(1)
 def profile(self):
     self.client.get("/profile/", headers=self.headers)

class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
    task_set = UserBehavior
    min_wait = 5000
    max_wait = 9000
```

In my case calling `sign_in`, returns a `key` which I then use as a token for my requests. Hope this helps, I am pretty new to Locust as well.